# How to Create Global Variable in Java Implementation of Hadoop MapReduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Now I want to create a global double variable(member) which could be accessed and changed by every mapper/reducer in a MapReduce job. At first I tried to state a static double member in my main java file, but it seems to be problematic since each mapper/reducer runs on a separate JVM and the member could be changed and accessed correctly.

I know that for int variable there is `counter` mechanism. But if I want to create a global double variable, how can I do that?

***My final goal is to sum up something that is double format in all mappers/reducers. If I cannot or should not create global variables, is there any other way that I can achieve that goal?***

Comment: Global mutable variables are basically the opposite of what you can do with map/reduces.  Don't even try to do it.  Even if you could mimic it, that would defeat the entire purpose of map/reduces and stop parallelization from taking effect.

Comment: @LouisWasserman But what if I want to sum up something that is double in mappers or reducers?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I have added that into the questions.

Comment: If you want to sum up double values, have your mappers return the sum of the values they received, and have the reducers sum up their inputs.  You have to restrict yourself to local variables, but you can do operations like summing in that style.

Answer (score 2):

Where are these doubles coming from? If they are in the input data, you can do it as a normal MR job. Have your mappers always output the same key, and the value to be summed. Use combiners to sum locally in each mapper. Then use only one reducer and have it simply emit the total sum.

"Global" state is exactly what the Map-Reduce paradigm is trying to avoid. You must try to think about everything as doing different portions of work in separate mappers, and then combining/aggregating in reducers.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can treat double like integers. You can multiply any double by 100000 and store it in the Counter. In the reducer if you need it, just divide by 100000.

Comment: Yes. This is tricky. But I think since this is against the concept of distributed computing, I should find some other solutions.

Comment: I still don't get how this is against the concept of distributed computing. If it is, then why do the counters exist? +1 for this answer